# Covariance matrix for 2 vectors with elements in the plane

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I am given 2 vectors of points in the $R^2$ plane and I want to compute the covariance matrix of the two vectors.

I know this will result in a 2x2 matrix. However, I am slightly confused. From Wikipedia, and from what I know, the covariance applies to vectors of random variables. In this case I do not have vectors of random variables, but rather a set of n samples from 2 random variables (one which yields the first vector and the other one which yields the second vector). I would like to use these samples in computing the variance, rather than estimating the two random variables in the underlying distributions.

I believe I lack some sort of understanding in the matter, and an explanation (rather than a simple answer) would be more than welcome.

Edit: this issue arises from me trying to understand the matlab function `cov`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are treating your data as just two vectors of points, then what you are looking for is the *variance of each sample* (the word "sample" referring to the collection of the $n$ points) and the covariance between the two samples (which can be contained in a $2\times 2$ matrix, with variances in the main diagonal and the covariance off-diagonal). This is of course *not* what is meant by "covariance matrix" (or "cross-covariance matrix" between two random vectors).

This matrix you are looking for can be written as 
(bar denoting the sample mean)

$$ V = \left[\begin{matrix}
\frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 - \bar x^2 & \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i - \bar x \bar y \\
\frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i - \bar x \bar y & \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i^2 - \bar y^2 \\
\end{matrix} \right]$$

...where $x_i$ and $y_i$ denote the points from each sample.

Again, this is not what is called the "covariance between two random vectors", it is just "variance-covarinace between two sets of points".

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. The confusion came from the name which was given to me (ie. covariance matrix).

Answer (score 0):

If each of the vectors contains two different variables, e.g. x,y, and you have n vectors, then you must compute mean value for each variable and then construct a vector of residuals by computing mean difference of each variable across whole sample.

$A=(x_1,y_1), B=(x_2,y_2)$

$C=\frac{A+B}{2}$

$D=\sqrt{\frac{(A-C)^2+(B-C)^2}{2}}$  ... operations hold for each vector element separately

The covariance matrix is then $\begin{pmatrix}
        D(1)\cdot{D}(1) & D(1)\cdot{D}(2)\\
        D(1)\cdot{D}(2) & D(2)\cdot{D}(2)\\ \end{pmatrix}
$

Note: for just two measurements, you should use corrected standard deviation, that is

$D=\sqrt{\frac{(A-C)^2+(B-C)^2}{n-1}}=\sqrt{(A-C)^2+(B-C)^2}$